# No SIGTTOU when Background Process Writing to STDOUT

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system

In the following code, after I call `setpgid` for the child process, the child process should be in its own process group (becomes background group) while the parent process remains in the foreground group. I use `strace` to track the signal. The `ls` process successfully writes to STDOUT while no `SIGTTOU` arises. When a background process writes to the terminal, wouldn't it get `SIGTTOU`?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      perror(msg);                                  \
      _exit(1);                                     \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

int main () {
  int ls_pid;
  char *ls_argv[] = { "ls", NULL };

  CHECK(ls_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!ls_pid) {
    CHECK(setpgid(0, 0), "child setpgid error");
    CHECK(execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv), "execvp error");
  } else {
    sleep(2);
  }
  CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");

  printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Comment: I believe it's an option but I don't know how to change it. Some time ago the default has changed, from sending SIGTTOU, to not sending it and just letting the output appear.

Comment: Try running `stty tostop` to enable getting SIGTTOU in that terminal.

Comment: Curious, why use a macro instead of a function, maybe `inline`?

Comment: @chux I don't really know. It looks cool.

Comment: regarding: `CHECK(setpgid(0, 0), "child setpgid error");`  the pid of the child is seen in the parent as 0 HOWEVER, that is not its' actual pid.  before calling this statement, syntax: `pid_t = getpid( void )` to obtain the actual pid value.  NOTE: the group id of 0 is for `root`, probably NOT what you want to use.  Note: group IDs have nothing to do with 'is the process running in foreground or background?`

Comment: it is poor programming practice to declare a function via a `#define` statement.  Much better to just give it the modifier: `inline`

Comment: you're calling `setpgid()` in parent process

Comment: @user3629249 According to the man page, `setpgid() sets the PGID of the process specified by pid to pgid.  If pid is zero, then the process ID of the calling process is used.  If pgid is zero, then the PGID of the process specified by pid is made  the  same  as  its process  ID.` So `setpgid(0, 0)` should be fine. I use `#define` because I don't want type checking.

Comment: @K.Miao,  regarding type checking.. Lets remember that the contents of a macro (as defined via a `#define` statement) is simply replacing the text of the macro name, in the source code, during preprocessing.  When the compiler gets the modified source code, then the type checking is performed.  So the type checking is still performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells usually support *job control* and allow processes to run in background (like `some-command &`) so it makes more sense to by default allow background processes to output to the terminal without receiving `SIGTTOU`.

To enable it you can run `stty tostop` (`stty -tostop` for disabling) which turns on the `TOSTOP` flag of the terminal.

See following example:

```
[STEP 101] # stty -a | grep tostop
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
                                                           ^^^^^^^
[STEP 102] # sh -c 'echo hello world' &
[1] 39554
[STEP 103] # hello world

[1]+  Done                    sh -c 'echo hello world'
[STEP 104] #
[STEP 105] # stty tostop
[STEP 106] # stty -a | grep tostop
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase tostop -echoprt
                                                           ^^^^^^
[STEP 107] #
[STEP 108] # sh -c 'echo hello world' &
[1] 39558
[STEP 109] #

[1]+  Stopped                 sh -c 'echo hello world'
[STEP 110] #
```